# How do I programmatically restart OS X using the kAERestart AppleEvent in Swift?

Tags: cocoa, swift

I am new to both ObjC & Swift and am looking to understand how to programmatically restart OS X using the kAERestart AppleEvent in Swift.

Can someone point me to a Swift implementation of https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1134/_index.html or something similar?

Comment: That code is neither Objective-C nor Swift. It is C. But you can _call_ it from Swift, by way of Objective-C, and that's going to be your best bet. You can't rewrite it _in_ Swift. - Now, as to whether that 10-year-old Carbon code is going to _work_, I've no idea. I'd be surprised, but you never know.

Comment: That Code does not work.